# How to implement Proxy connection using Openssl BIO related function?

Tags: sockets, openssl

I am inheriting a code from someone who uses OpenSSL to create a non-blocking socket through `*bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(*ssl_ctx);` and connect to the remote web service using TLS.

But right now, there is an additional request to support connecting to the same TLS service through a proxy (squid).

From my understanding (correct me if I am wrong), if connection to the proxy server, the client first basically sends an unencrypted connection like the following for authorization:

```http
CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com:443
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: curl-6.1.0
Proxy-Authorization: Basic cHJveHk6cHJveHk=
```

Once authorized, it sends the encrypted text using the same socket.

So usually, what I do is once connected to the Proxy server, I generate the header above, and once done, I apply SSL traffic through the same socket.

Is it possible using the `BIO_DO_CONNECT(host_name:port)`, perform authorization using `BIO_READ`, and `BIO_WRITE` against the proxy server, before cipher all subsequently once authorized successfully?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. Create the socket connection to the proxy, send an unencrypted request and read its unencrypted response, and if successful then call `BIO_do_handshake()` to initiate the TLS handshake with the target server before sending any further encrypted data to the target server.